# Flash Color Space

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, psd

My (eciRGB) pictures look a little bit green, when imported in flash. I found out (but I'm not completely shure), that flash uses sRGB color space. In another forum I found out that flash uses no color profiles and it doesnt matter which one I chose, I have to export my pictures for the web.

I have animations whith lots of frames, so the most comfortable way would be to import the psd directly into the library. Is that wrong, if I want to have correct colors?

Comment: I think the problem lies within your .psd file entirely. Try changing the color profile in Photoshop or copy-paste all your layers in a new .psd document with the right settings..

Comment: Yes, I found that out already. I'm currently using sRGB and everything is fine. Thanks anyway.